# Euler Project 5 in java, why is there a different result?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
/* Smallest multiple */
/*
 * 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each
 *  of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.What 
 *  is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible 
 *  by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?
 */
public class SmallestMultiple {
    public static int gcd(int m, int n){
        if(n>m){
            int temp = m;
            m = n;
            n = temp;
        }
        int gcdNum = m;
        while(m != 0){
            m = gcdNum%n;
            gcdNum = n;
            n = m;
        }
        return gcdNum;
    }
    private static int lcm(int m, int n){
        return m*n/gcd(m,n);
    }
    static int multiple(int start, int end){
        if(start > end){
            int temp = end;
            end = start;
            start = temp;
        }
        else if(start == end)
            return start;
        else
            return lcm(end, multiple(start, end-1));
        return multiple(start, end);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(multiple(11,19)); // line a--Which is equal to multiple(1,19) 
        System.out.println(multiple(11,20)); // line b--Which is equal to multiple(1,20)
    }
}
```

I think the answer multiple(1,19) and multiple(1,20) will get the same result. But with my code, they are different, **multiple(1,19)=232792560**(the right answer)and **multiple(1,20)=18044195** which is the wrong answer!!! I know there is many much more simple algorithms, but I just want to know where is my problem...
   Who can tell me the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `int` overflow when you compute

```
Prelude> 232792560 * 20
4655851200
Prelude> it `quotRem` (2^32)
(1,360883904)
```

Thus you obtain `360883904 / 20 = 18044195`.

You can

- use `long` or
- compute `m * (n/gcd(n,m))`

to avoid the overflow (the second method won't take you much farther, if the upper limit is 23, `int` is too small to hold the result).

Comment: Thank you very much, I have got the cause from your answer! Thanks agin!!! Since I am newbie of stackoverflow, I couldn't vote up for other person(reputation less than 15 -.-!!!), such a pity~

Comment: @mitcc You can't upvote, but you can accept an answer and by such mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is pretty much just an integer overflow.

The largest `int`number in Java is `Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647`.

At some point you try to run `lcm( 20, 232792560 )`. The latter being the result for `multiplay(1,19)`.

Inside your function, you try to compute `m*n/gcd(m,n)`.

With `m == 20`, `n == 18044195` and `gcd(m,n) == 20`, this gets `20 * 18044195 / 20`.

The first product is actually `20 * 18044195 == 4655851200`, which is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, thus an overflow happens and your total result runs bad.

One solution would be to switch to a `long` type everywhere, which has a maximum value of `Long.MAX_VALUE == 9223372036854775807` .